# Should I choose a "best" answer if it's a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accepted-answer, community-wiki

[This question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/468/dos-and-donts-for-an-effective-bedtime-ritual) is a community wiki, but as the asker I can still choose one answer as the *accepted answer.*

Why should I (not?) accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If one of the wiki answers stands out as "most helpful" to your situation, accept it. There's no implication that the accepted answer is the "best" answer or even the "correct" answer; Only that the accepted answer is the one *you* found most helpful.

But some questions are made wiki because the value of the answer(s) is in having the *entire* list of posts contributed equally by all the participants. If there is no expectation of receiving a most-preferred answer, don't accept one. It's perfectly legitimate not to have an accepted answer. That's why the [accept rate calculation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/) excludes community wiki posts.